# How can a pre-send script retrieve parameters of a parameterized Jenkins job?

Tags: email-ext

I would like to cancel email sending based on the value of a boolean parameter of a parameterized job. The parameter is named "skip.email".

I tried to write a pre-send script with following content but it doesn't work :

```
def env = System.getenv()
logger.println("Should I skip email ? " + env['skip.email'])
cancel = env['skip.email']
```

Here is what I see in the logs :

```
Should I skip email ? null
```

I tried to print out all environment variables, but none of the parameters of my parameterized Jenkins job are in the list.

Please help me out, thank you in advance !

Comment: Seems that nobody has an answer :-/

Answer (score 7):

The pre-send script provides a variable named "build", which is of a type that inherits from [AbstractBuild](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#getBuildVariables()). Use the [getBuildVariables](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html#getBuildVariables()) method to retrieve a Map that includes the parameterized variables.

## Example

I have a parameterized variable named "target" that describes a deployment environment. I want emails to only be sent to QA if the target environment was QA's environment.

```
if (!build.getBuildVariables().get("target").equals("qa")) {   
  // cancel variable cancels the email send when set to true
  cancel = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

tday03 answer seems correct but is not working for me, I'm injecting the vars with [Environment Injector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), I don't know if that's the issue. Anyway I ended up with this script:

```
def env = build.getEnvironment()
String official = env['OFFICIAL'];

if ((official != null) && official.equals("true")) {
  cancel = false;
} else {
  cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of a Parameterized job are not environment variables!! They can't be accessed that way. If you want to access them, use the [Environment Inject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to add them to the environment as a build step and then follow these steps. It should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`build.getEnvironment(TaskListener.NULL)` if injecting environment variables as a prior step. If looking just to get the build parameters, `build.buildvariables` should work just fine.

Comment: For me there was no need to specify `TaskListener.NULL` as parameter, just `build.getEnvironment()` did suffice. Although I don't understand why because indeed the getEnvironment() is defined with nonnull argument (https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/61a8fed2594989ca14f31179b75ce26e5157cb3b/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.java#L956).